# how to avoid Div overlap when text transform

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design the text in the div to vertical and I see the div overlaps one another. How can I avoid that?. also The border of the div in the top is not visible.

```
<div style="width: 576px;border: 1px solid black;margin: 25px;padding: 25px;text-align: center;height: 393px;transform: rotate(90deg);float:left;clear: left;">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div>
        <h5>TEST</h5></div><br>
    <span>1/2</span>
</div>
<div style="width: 576px;border: 1px solid black;margin: 25px;padding: 25px;text-align: center;height: 393px;transform: rotate(90deg);float:left;clear: left;">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div>
        <h5>TEST</h5></div><br>
    <span>2/2</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It overlaps because of the rotation. Your divs are `576px` broad and `393px` tall. The rotation point is by default in the center, and because your box has a bigger width than height, it overlaps. If you want that your margin still appears to be `25px`, apply the following margins:

```
top, bottom: (576 - 393) / 2 + 25 = 116.5
left, right: (393 - 576) / 2 + 25 = -66.5
```

The code would look like this:

```
margin: 117px -67px;
```

Hope this helps!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yq4ob9ao/1/

```css
#div1, #div2 {
    width: 576px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 117px -67px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 393px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    float:left;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div>
        <h5>TEST</h5></div><br>
    <span>1/2</span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div>
        <h5>TEST</h5></div><br>
    <span>2/2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your margins are calculated before `transform: rotate` property transforms the divs. You need to update the top margins for individual divs to adjust their positions.

In the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y4jvah8d/), I'm using `margin-top: 100px;` for the first div and `margin-top: 160px;` for the second div as examples.

Comment: Thank you.. for your solution